# Get the mediaPlayer of the videoView in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

Is it possible to get a reference to the mediaPlayer instance that the videoView is using, preferably right inside its ctor? If so, how?

Since the videoView doesn't have as much listeners as the mediaPlayer, I would like to have the ability to reach the mediaPlayer for extra control and better events handling.

Comment: You can probably do it via [reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html).

Comment: reflection is too messy and too dangerous. is it possible to extend the videoView and get the mediaPlayer there instead ?

Answer (score 16):

you can listener from VideoView.

```
VideoView mVideoView=new VideoView();
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener( new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer pMp) {
   //use a global variable to get the object
  }
});
```

Alternatively if you are only interested on Media Player Events you can use any of these and these are implemented on VideoView and these are basically MediaPlayer events.

```
void    setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener l)
void    setOnErrorListener(MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener l)
void    setOnInfoListener(MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener l)
void    setOnPreparedListener(MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener l)
```

All these function will give a Media Player instance also.

Comment: even though i've asked this question long ago , i remember what i wanted : a lot of control and being notified of all of the events in this view : playback status events (pause,start,stop,seek) , error events , buffering status , etc ... mediaPlayer has all of those (though not sure how well they work and how) , yet videoView has only some .

Comment: Events on VideoView(e.g. setOnInfoListener(MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener l)) are available only from API level 17, so what if I want to support to lower API levels ?

Comment: You can setOnInfoListener of the MediaPlayer object found. Available > API 3.

Comment: `setOnPreparedListener()` is not working, `onPrepared()` is never called!

Comment: @nburk make sure you're not already calling `setOnPreparedListener()` further down in your code. That second call would replace this one if you did have one. (hope this helps)