# Stretch to fill VideoView, aspect ratio of VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview, aspect-ratio

I try to stretch video in aim to fill videoview. The target is to create view that in device look like the first pic (like it look in layout preview).

Most of the answers to this questions refer to [this link](http://blog.kasenlam.com/2012/02/android-how-to-stretch-video-to-fill.html).

I tried this but I still didn't fill video view.

This my layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/search_gren_screen">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/go_back"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onclick"
            android:text="Try again" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back_to_pick_song"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Select another song" 
            android:onClick="onclick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_continue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onclick"
            android:text="Amazing, continue!" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <VideoView 
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here you have a preview of my declared layout:

[image]

However, the result on the device is different:

[image]

Comment: Your layout code is okay to fulfill your need. But keep in mind that `VideoView` will shrink/stretch with respect to the Video playing in it.

Comment: ok, so i need change the aspect ratio of the media recorder mean to add mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);   i try this and it'n work ...  ???

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38971707/1153703

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try to make your outer layout a relative layout and put the VideoView inside that.

Something like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/trim_container"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/buttonContainer"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <Button
          android:id="@+id/go_back"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="center"  
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="onclick"
          android:text="Try again" />

     <Button
          android:id="@+id/back_to_pick_song"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:text="Select another song" 
          android:onClick="onclick" />

    <Button
          android:id="@+id/btn_continue"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="onclick"
          android:text="Amazing, continue!" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <VideoView
     android:id="@+id/VideoView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_below="@id/buttonContainer"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It fuc..ing workssss!! This is the easiest way to achieve this thing. I have been wasting a lot of time trying to achieve this. Thanks a lot!!!!!!

Comment: i wasted hours trying to make that happen, Thanks a lot man

Answer (score 2):

video view should be inside to the Relative Layout. Here is an example given below. In my case, it works very fine with a FullScreen Button.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:id="@+id/videoVIewLinId"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"

            >
                <VideoView
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/videoViewId"
                    />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/fullScreenBtnIdOnlineMedia"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_full_screen"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"

                    />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fill_parent` method doesn't work for me.

Finally I use this library, works great!

https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/video-crop