# Video view is not showing properly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-videoview

I want to play video in videoView from internet, so I have written the xml code as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
app:cardElevation="11dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:clickable="true" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDescriptionVideo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:text="Problem Description"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAddressVideo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewDescriptionVideo"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textViewDescriptionVideo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewDescriptionVideo"
        android:text="Address" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDistanceVideo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Distance" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBarVideo"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewDistanceVideo"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTotalRVideo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewDescriptionVideo"
        android:text="Total Rating" />

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**The code to listen onTouch event of VideoView is shown below**

```
video_Holder.videoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        try {

                            currentPost = recievedList.get(video_Holder.getAdapterPosition());
                            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Buffering Video", false);
                            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                            mediacontroller = new MediaController(context);

                            Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(currentPost.getDownloadLink());
                            video_Holder.videoView.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
                            video_Holder.videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

                            video_Holder.videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    video_Holder.videoView.start();

                                }
                            });

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

**Resulting view that is created inside my app(when I run on device)**
[image]

> Since I have set the width of videoView as match_parent then why
>   it(videoView) is showing improperly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VideoView to match parent height and keep aspect ratio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603553/videoview-to-match-parent-height-and-keep-aspect-ratio)

Comment: This question is already answered [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603553/videoview-to-match-parent-height-and-keep-aspect-ratio)