# Unable to display complete width of video with Video View

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-videoview

By using android `VideoView` can't display the complete width of video at the screen. Right side of the screen displays the background image. That means 75% of screen width (left side) displays the video and other 25% of the screen (right side) displays the background image.

Below is my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
final VideoView videoView  =(VideoView)child.findViewById(R.id.video_player);

                MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
                mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                Uri uri=Uri.parse("http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/AndroidCommercial.3gp");
                videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
                videoView.requestFocus();


                videoView.start();
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/video_player"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

How to display the full width of video in `android-video view` ?

Comment: Have a look into [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603553/videoview-to-match-parent-height-and-keep-aspect-ratio).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Relative Layout` and put `VideoView` inside that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```