# Avoiding video stretching in a VideoView

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mp4, android-videoview

I have a stranger problem using **VideoView**.

Using some .mp4 (coded using ffmpeg) video i have this problem:

[image: Video is stretch]

The video is stretch to cover all screen-width.

But using .mp4 video coded using a different software(i don't remember it)
the result is:

[image: Video is not stretch]

The aspect ratio is preserved.

This is my layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/allenamento_activity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/videoView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </VideoView>

            <---- OTHER XML CODE ------>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can i prevent the stretching of the video?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VideoView to match parent height and keep aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603553/videoview-to-match-parent-height-and-keep-aspect-ratio)

Comment: @BertoGT any solution for this?

Answer (score -3):

The scrollview and all children are all set to:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

which would entail all children will be the same width as the screen/primary layout.

You either need to calculate the needed height/width or wrap content on width and height.

The onMeasure method may be of use here?

Comment: Searching on the web, i tried to use `Relative Layout` as VideoView's container and i tried to compute its widht necessary to preserve the aspect ratio but without results...