# why I can not access my codes inside "on prepared listener" within "on click listener" in fragment to mute my video?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm new in android, and I got a problem in muting my video inside OnClickListener within fragment. I use 3 different dynamic fragment. my second fragment has to play a video. I have a mute button in that fragment to Make my video mute and unmute after I press it again. I use OnPreparedListener in my Button OnClickListener, but it absolutely do nothing without any error!! surprisingly it does work well when I use it outside of my Button OnClickListener. so why It happened and how can I use it inside OnClickListener?

here is my MainActivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FirstFragment.OnFirstFragmentInteractionListener , SecondFragment.OnSecondFragmentInteractionListener , ThirdFragment.OnLastFragmentInteractionListener {

private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // first transaction for my first fragment
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_frame, new FirstFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void onFirstFragmentInteraction(Fragment a) {// it make a
//transaction after I finish my first fragment to second fragment I do not
//copy the first fragment codes for brief
    FragmentTransaction newTransaction = 
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    newTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, new SecondFragment());
    newTransaction.commit();
    if(a != null)
        newTransaction.remove(a); // I use "a" to passes first fragment 
        // to remove it here
}

@Override
public void onVideoCompletListenerIntaction() { // it happened when
// my second fragment video finished and it work well
    FragmentTransaction newTransaction = 
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    newTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, new ThirdFragment());
    newTransaction.commit();
}
```

and here is my video fragment

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {


private OnSecondFragmentInteractionListener onSecondFragInteaction;
private View view;
private ImageButton ibntMuteSecFrag;
private VideoView videoViewMain;
private AudioManager audio;
private float videoVolume;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);

        ibntMuteSecFrag = view.findViewById(R.id.ibtn_mute_second_frag);
        videoViewMain =  view.findViewById(R.id.vdvw_main_clip);

        audio = (AudioManager) 
        getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        String videoPath = "android.resource://" + 
        getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.my_wedding_main_video;
        videoViewMain.setVideoPath(videoPath);
        videoViewMain.start();

        ibntMuteSecFrag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onIbntMuteSecFragListener();
            }
        });

    return view;
}



public void onIbntMuteSecFragListener() {

    if (flagIsMuteBtnPress)
        videoVolume = 0;
    else
        videoVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    videoViewMain.setOnPreparedListener(new 
    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // compiler never get here, I use Log.d and notice that
                mp.setVolume(videoVolume, videoVolume);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof 
    SecondFragment.OnSecondFragmentInteractionListener) {
        onSecondFragInteaction = 
    (SecondFragment.OnSecondFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    onSecondFragInteaction = null;
}

public interface OnSecondFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onVideoCompletListenerIntaction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SecondFragment.this.onIbntMuteSecFragListener();
```

thats because you actually in the anonymous class View.OnclickListener() and this instance does not implement the method you try to reach from that outer scope of Fragment...

Comment: I do this "SecondFragment.this.onIbntMuteSecFragListener();" but still not work. would you please explain me more about your solution because I thick the problem might cause something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You set MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() too late. As I understand you start playing video before you set listener. So when listener was set player "Prepare event" has already passed.

Firstly you need to set listener and only then start playing video. In this case listener will be triggered.

Comment: the mute event is an event that might happened or not, but playing video is what this fragment reason and with starting second fragment it must start, so how can I set listener first?

Comment: You have to set listener before you call this method `videoViewMain.start();` But in this case you wan't be able to set volume with your current solution. You need to have reference to mediaPlayerCheck. Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185874/get-the-mediaplayer-of-the-videoview-in-android) to understand how to get reference to mediaPlayer. As I see this isn't good solution too, but at lest is should work.

Comment: I change my code and set listener before I call videoViewMain.start(); but is still does not work :(

Comment: Sorry, my fault. According to mediaPlayer life cycle diagram, we need to set listener before `videoViewMain.setVideoPath(videoPath);`

Comment: I do it but still noting :(((

Comment: The Listener isn't being called or mute button doesn't work?

Comment: Prepare listener inside your click listener won't be called. You are setting listener each time when user click button. But because event has already passed prepare listener isn't called. It will be called only if you reset video path and restart player.

Comment: listener is called and button work well with other stuff that programmed to do , like changing face of button or make the button pressed flags, I do not copy other button's code for brief, the problem only is that the thread can not reach inside of OnPrepared to set the video volume. but when I use the onPrepared on OnCreateView  It works well and video volume has change, but inside my button OnClickListener no volume changing happened.

Comment: so how can I mute my video? (without changing device volume)

Comment: Check out my first comment for this answer. It has a link to related question. In onPrepared method you receive one method argument is media player instance. To change volume you need this instance. You can save it as class parameter(field) and then use it in your click listener. To be honest this isn't good solution, but for you as for new developer it's ok, later you will figure out why it's not good.

Answer (score 0):

The `onPreparedListener.onPrepared()` is only called if you set it up before `onStart()`.
The [state diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDNBW.gif) illustrates that a MediaPlayer object must first enter the Prepared state before playback can be started.
So, First set the `onPreparedListener.onPrepared()` and then call `videoViewMain.start();`.

Comment: I change my code and define onPrepared() befor videoViewMain.start(); but it still does not work :(

Comment: According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#prepare%28%29) , after setting the datasource and the display surface, you need to either call `prepare()` or `prepareAsync()`. You are playing locally, so call `prepare()`.

Comment: so Ranjit what would have cause this? as you said, I set my listener before start() and before setVideoPath(videoPath) but the problem is still on.